# there's this theme for android i don't understand the characters, can you help me translate it? (the characters are on images bellow)

Tags: translation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjY77.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3uZP.jpg

theme name  is Fo mo dao xian buddhism, also would apreciate if you tell me what does that mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The big character on the first image is 魔 (demon) and the poem is  a statement from the perspective of 魔

~

> The big character on the second image is 道 (The Truth/ The Way) and the poem is a statement from the perspective of 道

In the philosophy sense 魔 and 道 are the opposite of each other:

- 道 represents 'enlightened mind' that extended to 'just, peaceful, kind, selfless and everything positive'
- 魔 represents 'fallen mind' that extended to 'unjust, violent, cruel, selfish and everything negative'

As for the two poems:

1. 天地不仁何乞憐，我以我血染青天，魔前一扣三千年，回首凡塵不做仙

(The universe is unkind, what is the use of begging for mercy? I'd use my blood to paint the blue sky red; Three thousand years since I had submitted to the way of demon, looking back at the mortal world, I'd rather not being a god)

2. 曾經滄海難為水，除卻巫山不是雲，萬花叢中懶回顧，半緣修道半緣君

(Experienced the vast ocean, it is hard to be a pool of still water; Experienced the grand cloud-sea on top of Wushan,  other clouds are no longer impressive;  In the middle of an endless flower field, I don't have the desire to look back; Either you can achieve all these or not, half depend on the study of Dao and half depend on yourself )

Comment: thank you for your help :)
if it's not hard for you, could you please translate this one too?
https://imgur.com/a/5LbDE0U
https://imgur.com/a/2C6iHVz

also do you know the source where these poems come from? or is it just fan made?

Comment: these poems  are fan made, they borrowed some verses from famous poems like 曾經滄海難為水，除卻巫山不是雲, but the rest are original